# VFP 5 COPY TO command

Tags: unicode, visual-foxpro

I need to copy my cursor information into text file that is encoded using UTF-8.

My current command was :-

```
COPY TO (FILE NAME) DELIMITED WITH CHARACTER ";"
```

By default the text file was saved into ANSI, how can I make it save into UTF-8?

EDIT: I am using VFP 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , try using StrConv()

strconv(filetostr(FILE NAME),10)

Comment: I have tried, but VFP 5 doesn't recognize FILETOSTR. I need an alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, this is the only way i know to do this. Hope someone can deliver you further information!

Answer (score 0):

1.Convert all *Character* and *Memo* fields into UTF-8:

```
update table1 set field1=STRCONV(field1, 9)
```

This converts all non-ANSI characters into UTF-8 encoding.

2. Export it using your *COPY TO* command.

Comment: Thank you, I guess this will work but I havent tried it. My data are stored in cursor and I have lots of fields. Do you mind to share a better way that I can use to update all the fields with STRCONV instead of updating them one by one?

Comment: For example, Iterate all fields in a loop, executing `STRCONV()` on `character` fields. Or, use a batch conversion tool like _DBF Commander Pro_.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Oleg's suggestion, you can cycle through all fields in the given table by...

```
USE C:\SomePath\YourTable.dbf
*/ Get list of all fields in the table's structure
lnF = AFIELDS( laF, "YourTable" )
lcUpdFlds = ""
*/ Prepare a field for allowing comma between multiple fields
*/ but first time in is the "SET" command instead.
lcNextFld = "set "
FOR lnI = 1 TO lnF
   */ Is it a character-based field
   IF laF[ lnI, 2] = "C" OR laF[ lnI, 2] = "M" 
      lcFld = laF[ lnI, 1]
      lcUpdFlds = lcUpdFlds + lcNextFld + lcFld + " = STRCONV( " + lcFld + ", 9) " 
      */ Any subsequent character based fields will have a COMMA
      */ added between them.
      lcNextFld = ", "
   ENDIF
ENDFOR
```

update YourTable &lcUpdFlds

Modified to do ONE update command and hit ALL columns vs running multiple updates... Especially on a LARGER table